# Delete elements of a List, using a condition

Tags: python

Hello I'm learning to program in Python to manipulate data bases and I can't make this simple task. Please someone help me.
I have this list

```
CIS=['4998200lp','2159140lp','02546or']
```

I want to get this result:

```
CIS=['4998200lp','2159140lp','2546or']
```

I was trying something like:

```
for x in CIS:
    izq= x[:1]
    if izq == 0:
        CIS=[x.replace(x[:1],'') for x in CIS]
    print (CIS)
```

I just want to delete the first element of every string for the condition `izq == 0`.

Comment: So you just want to strip leading `'0'` characters?  What if the item was `'002546or'`?

Comment: Additionally, you're evaluating `izq == 0` with `0` as an integer. Changing it  to `izq == '0'` will help. Although the way you replace it is inefficient as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description doesn't match your example input/output which also differs from your code.

Based on the example input/output, I suspect what you're trying to do is strip a single leading `0` from any string that starts with `0`. And that's not too bad, but you can't do it in a `for` loop without having an index to assign back to. For that, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(CIS):
    if x.startswith('0'):  # or x[:1] == '0' if you really prefer
        CIS[i] = x[1:]
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension to replace `CIS`:

```
CIS = [x[1:] if x.startswith('0') else x for x in CIS]
```

and to mutate in place (rather than making a new `list`), use the same comprehension but assign to the full slice, which makes it behave like the spelled out loop in the first example:

```
CIS[:] = [x[1:] if x.startswith('0') else x for x in CIS]
```

The difference between examples #1/#3 and example #2 occurs if `CIS` was passed as an argument to a function, or otherwise is referenced in multiple places. In #1/#3, it's mutating the `list` in place, so all references will see the updates, in #2, it's reassigning `CIS`, but leaving the original `list` unchanged; if other references exist, they won't appear changed.

Note: If the goal is to remove *all* leading `0`s, then use `str.lstrip`, e.g.:

```
CIS = [x.lstrip('0') for x in CIS]
```

with similar adaptations for the other approaches. You don't even need to test for the presence of `0` in that case, as `lstrip` will return the `str` unmodified if it doesn't begin with `0`.

Comment: And for a fun functional version using `itertools.starmap` and `itertools.repeat`: `list(starmap(str.lstrip, zip(CIS, repeat('0'))))`.

Comment: And by "fun" I mean "a lot slower than `[x.lstrip('0') for x in CIS]`, so it shouldn't be used."

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Actually, you can skip `starmap` and `zip` if you're using the Py3 version of `map` (in Py2, can be found on `future_builtins`), and just do: `list(map(str.lstrip, CIS, repeat('0')))` But yes, likely to be slower in most cases (if it ever gets faster, it would only be for huge inputs).

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to remove the first zero of every string, utilize the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method. Also, don't look for an integer 0. Look for a string '0'.

Finally, you can simplify your implementation with doing this all in a comprehension, creating a new list with your new data:

```
[w[1:] if w.startswith('0') else w for w in CIS]
```

Outputs:

```
['4998200lp', '2159140lp', '2546or']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to delete first character of every elements that starts with `0`:

```
CIS=['4998200lp','2159140lp','02546or']
for i,v in enumerate(CIS):
    if v.startswith('0'):
        CIS[i] = v[1:]

CIS  # ['4998200lp', '2159140lp', '2546or']
```

Comment: Note: Unlike the OP's code (and other answers), this will raise an exception if any of the strings in the `list` are the empty string. Either use a slice `v[:1] == '0'` or use `v.startswith('0')` to avoid this problem without needing to introduce a special case for the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your loop contained a very close approach to a working solution:

```
CIS=['4998200lp','2159140lp','02546or']
CIS=[x.replace(x[:1],'') for x in CIS]
```

but this would strip all first elements. To only replace them if they are `'0'` (notice that's not the same as the `integer`: `0`) you need to incorporate you `if ... else ...` into the list-comprehension:

```
CIS=['4998200lp','2159140lp','02546or']
CIS=[x.replace(x[:1],'',1) if x[:1] == '0' else x for x in CIS ]
```

The `if ... else ...` syntax might be a bit strange but just try to read the code aloud: "Insert the replaced x if the first character is a zero or if not insert x, for every x in CIS".

The other answers contain much more sophisticated approaches but I just wanted to add this answer to give you a heads-up that you were on the right track!

But it's generally a bad idea to use a list-comprehension inside a `for` loop if they iterate over the same `iterable`. Mostly you just want one of them.